# Apache CloudStack Installation Error at setingup the database

Tags: cloud, citrix, apache-cloudstack, private-cloud

I am a student and setting up research environment for Apache CloudStack. I am at the setup where i need to setup the database. When i am running the below command it getting stuck at "Processing Encryption".I tried to look on internet but didn't found any help.

```
[root@csman /]# cloudstack-setup-databases cloud:abbas123@127.0.0.1 --deploy-as=root:nimda123
Mysql user name:cloud                                                           [ OK ]
Mysql user password:******                                                      [ OK ]
Mysql server ip:127.0.0.1                                                       [ OK ]
Mysql server port:3306                                                          [ OK ]
Mysql root user name:root                                                       [ OK ]
Mysql root user password:******                                                 [ OK ]
Checking Cloud database files ...                                               [ OK ]
Checking local machine hostname ...                                             [ OK ]
Checking SELinux setup ...                                                      [ OK ]
Detected local IP address as 192.168.56.12, will use as cluster management server node IP[ OK ]
Preparing /etc/cloudstack/management/db.properties                              [ OK ]
Applying /usr/share/cloudstack-management/setup/create-database.sql             [ OK ]
Applying /usr/share/cloudstack-management/setup/create-schema.sql               [ OK ]
Applying /usr/share/cloudstack-management/setup/create-database-premium.sql     [ OK ]
Applying /usr/share/cloudstack-management/setup/create-schema-premium.sql       [ OK ]
Applying /usr/share/cloudstack-management/setup/server-setup.sql                [ OK ]
Applying /usr/share/cloudstack-management/setup/templates.sql                   [ OK ]
Processing encryption ...                                                       ^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/cloudstack-setup-databases", line 604, in <module>
    o.run()
  File "/usr/bin/cloudstack-setup-databases", line 593, in run
    self.processEncryptionStuff()
  File "/usr/bin/cloudstack-setup-databases", line 419, in processEncryptionStuff
    encryptDBPassword()
  File "/usr/bin/cloudstack-setup-databases", line 408, in encryptDBPassword
    self.putDbProperty('db.cloud.password', formatEncryptResult(encrypt(dbPassword)))
  File "/usr/bin/cloudstack-setup-databases", line 392, in encrypt
    return runCmd(cmd).strip('\r\n')
  File "/usr/bin/cloudstack-setup-databases", line 49, in runCmd
    stdout, stderr = process.communicate()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 732, in communicate
    stdout, stderr = self._communicate(input, endtime)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 1328, in _communicate
    stdout, stderr = self._communicate_with_poll(input, endtime)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 1400, in _communicate_with_poll
    ready = poller.poll(self._remaining_time(endtime))
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Please let me know if any additional information is required. I am really new to this and don't have clue what needs to be done to solve this. Help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which config is goofed up. Can you go through following steps and post if you have not followed any steps mentioned in post?

http://www.cloudometry.in/2015/03/apache-cloudstack-implementation-step_96.html

Are you deploying in virtual environment?